# Зависит от размер участка памяти от типа указателя?

Tags: c++, c

Зависит ли размер участка памяти, доступного с помощью разыменования адреса (указателя) от его типа? Если да, то почему

Comment: В общем случае -- нет. `char *` может указывать на один символ, а может на массив из N символов. С другой стороны, при разыменовании `T *` будет прочитано не менее  `sizeof(T)` байт.